# How to save audio from a rtsp source(codec mp4a) using gstreamer?

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, rtsp

I am able to receive and save the video stream at 1080p but getting the audio stream is the issue

Here is what I've tried.

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.168:554/ch01  ! queue ! "application/x-rtp,media=video" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location="test.ts"

above command works
the codec for the audio received is mp4a (aac encoded) 
command used to extract audio

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.168:554/ch01  ! queue ! "application/x-rtp,media=audio" ! rtpmp4adepay ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location="test.ts"

the file size is zero.
Requirement is to save both video and audio in a single (.ts) file

Comment: provide an example about what you have tried

Comment: I've edited the question with more info on what I've tried